# Getting Python 3.x setup for use on Google Cloud

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform

I'll preface this with that until last week, my entire experience with linux can be summarized by some long-forgotten class in school 10 years ago, plus my recent use of Git Bash on Windows. Bear with me!

I've recently started working with GCP to do data-sciency stuff. I created a VM instance to load and process a bunch of data using a Python script I wrote.

However, when I start the instance, I see that it's using Python 2.7, so I naturally tried to figure out how to install or update Python. [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) said that I'd likely have to build the library from source code, so that's what I learned how to do (thanks SO).

Now, as I'm trying to run my script, I keep getting errors due to missing modules. A little research told me that these are core library modules that are missing... As in they should be part of my Python environment already. So I keep `pip` installing these missing modules, but each and every time, I have to re-build Python from scratch in order for the newly installed modules to be recognized.

Let's just say, that's not fun for a Windows los... user.

So, how do I get a Python distribution that has all the regular libraries already installed, like I would on Windows?

Comment: The steps depend on the distribution. Look for articles like this one: https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/  OR https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu. Your explanation about `pip` problems is confusing. You don't rebuild Python from scratch. Also, I recommend learning about `virtualenv` or equivalent so that your Python dependencies are application local and not installed globally. Completing a beginner's course on Python will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I think I've settled on just using miniconda. And what do you mean "you don't rebuild python from scratch"? That's exactly what I did. I built it from source, got errors about a missing module, installed it with pip, then rebuilt. Then, I'd get another error about another missing core dependency, and do it over again.

Comment: If you want to be on the `bleeding` edge, install and build from source. Otherwise use a tested installation package as shown in the links.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I have no desire to be on the bleeding edge. I was just going by this verbage on the python.org downloads page: "For most Unix systems, you must download and compile the source code.", so I didn't look much farther. I figured that if there was an easier way they wouldn't use the word `must`. Silly me, but now I know better. Thanks a lot for those links, I'm checking them out now.

Comment: In the Linux world, you have distributions (CentOS, Red Hat, Ubuntu, etc.) Software vendors, the distributions, or their supporters, package applications such as Python into installable packages to eliminate the requirement of building from source.